# Can't open csv file in pandas due to unicode decoding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I saved a pandas dataframe as a csv using

```
df_to_save.to_csv(save_file_path)
```

but when I read it back in using

```
df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

I get an error message saying

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position
>   158: invalid start byte

I've tried forcing the encoding on reading it to be utf-8 by opening the csv file with

```
df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=False, encoding="utf-8",sep=',')
```

Really stuck, can anyone help?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post raw text data or a link to your actual csv, the encoding may not be what you think it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the encoding of your categorical data :

```
def my_func(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].str.decode('iso-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')
```

This function will change in-place the encoding of your categorical data.

Answer (score 3):

That character is not encoded in UTF-8.

You can reproduce it with ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)):

```
b'\xbf'.decode("utf-8", "strict")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-4db5a43b4577>", line 1, in <module>
    b'\xbf'.decode("utf-8", "strict")

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte
```

You can try a different encoding, that would solve the problem for this character:

```
b'\xbf'.decode("ISO-8859-1", "strict")
Out: '¿'
```

So your `read_csv` would change to:

```
df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

OR TO AVOID ENCODING PROBLEMS USE EXCEL (**also return DataFrames**)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('train_numeric.xlsx')
newTRAIN.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
```

THEN

```
newTEST_excel = pd.read_excel('train_numeric.xlsx')
newTEST_excel.head(2)
```

Comment: Tip... stop the textual "YELLING" ;-)