# "Illegal" characters in a csv file -different behavior by different programs

Tags: python, pandas, tr

I was trying to download the VAERS data file, [here](https://vaers.hhs.gov/data/datasets.html?) (the vaersdata file for 2021 in case you are wondering). Downloading was not a problem, it is the latter stages that confuse me. Opening the CSV with Excel works fine (though is super-slow, as we have learned to expect from Excel). Reading it in as a sqlite table works fine also. However, `pandas.read_csv` barfs, thusly:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 52327: invalid start byte
```

I tried to clean the file with:

```
tr -cd '[:print:]\n'
```

But for the first time in my checkered career, `tr` failed:

```
tr: Illegal byte sequence
```

Any suggestions on how to read the thing into python would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open csv file in pandas due to unicode decoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057758/cant-open-csv-file-in-pandas-due-to-unicode-decoding-error)

Comment: @rustyhu Yes, it does, thank you!!!! Do you know why tr fails? I would have thought it would just delete the `0xb0` but nooo.

Comment: Maybe `tr` can not process this invalid ASCII byte too. Advise you to read the manpage of it.